# How to fill a Struct type map from Mysql

Tags: mysql, dictionary, go

Im new in Golang.
This is the structure that I want to load and the problem is that there is the map [string] ChannelST which I don't know how to fill from Mysql

```
type StreamST struct {
    Name     string
    Channels map[string]ChannelST
}

type ChannelST struct {
    Name             string
    URL              string
    OnDemand         bool
    Debug            bool
    Status           int
    runLock          bool
    codecs           []av.CodecData
    sdp              []byte
    signals          chan int
    hlsSegmentBuffer map[int]SegmentOld
    hlsSegmentNumber int
    clients          map[string]ClientST
    ack              time.Time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact answer depends a lot on your database schema. I will attempt to give a generic answer. You could go 2 ways(as far as I know):

1. Use a library which does a lot of you in this regard like [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) or [gorm](https://gorm.io/index.html). These libraries will look at the exported fields in your struct and tags to automatically fill them.
2. Use the standard [sql](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Rows) library and do everything yourself. In this case you will need to use the `Rows.Scan` function to fill structs yourself.

In any case, your `StreamST` struct contains a map, which is a collection, so I assume you are joining two tables. In GORM you can specify relations and the library will take this into account. Though I am not sure if this only works for slices or maps as well, since GORM doesn't know which field of struct to use as index for the map.

When using the standard library, the rows returned are exactly the same as the result from the SQL query, so fields of your left table will be repeated and thus you need to write your own logic to turn this list of fields into the proper structure.

Lastly, you have a number of custom types like `av.CodecData`. If these correspond to single fields but in a custom format, you can implement custom encoding/decoding by letting these structs implement [sql.Scanner](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Scanner) and [driver.Valuer](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql/driver@go1.17.2#Valuer) interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have this but it's a list and i need it to be on a map(?).
I know it return a list but i dont know to fill the map[string]ChannelST.

func ListarDispositivos() ListaDispositivos {
 oLista := ListaDispositivos{}

 sqlQuery := `CALL listarDispositivos();`
 db.Open()
 rows, _ := db.Query(sqlQuery)

 for rows.Next() {
  var oChannel ChannelST
  rows.Scan(&oChannel.Name, &oChannel.URL, &oChannel.OnDemand, &oChannel.Debug, &oChannel.Status, &oChannel.runLock)
  oLista = append(oLista, oChannel)
 }

 db.Close()
 return oLista
}

Comment: That depends on the key of your map. If you want a map where the key is equal to `oChannel.Name` you can turn your slice/list into a map by declaring the map outside of the `for rows.Next()` loop (`oMap := make(map[string]ChannelST)`) and instead of using `oLista = append(oLista, oChannel)` you set a key in the map like `oMap[oChannel.Name] = oChannel`

Comment: Thanks you so much for help me